# Get Azure DevOps server (on-premises) data using Power Bi desktop connector

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I want to show analytics using power bi desktop from my azure devops server which is deployed on-premises but unable to connect while the error shows analytics extension is not available for on-premises server of devops. I also found the Odata endpoint method but is it possible to do it using connector? Please suggest.

Error i am getting as follows

[image]

When i go the provided link, i am unable to download analytics extension as 'Get it free' link is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Azure DevOps Server do you use? What error do you get when you get data from Azure DevOps Server?

Comment: Azure DevOps Server 2019. I updated the question and added the error which i am getting.

Comment: Unable to download that extension as it's link disabled. Check updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics is now available in Azure DevOps Server 2019. The latest version of Power BI has a new connector called "Azure DevOps Server" which supports Analytics Views.

[image]

Check the following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops

---

Your error has indicated the issue, you have to install Analytics extension in your Azure DevOps server:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics

Comment: The link you shared is for azure devops services which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did research and found the solution as Analytics extension can only be downloaded using the DevOps extension section and then it worked for me.